# How much does Firebase Realtime Database and Storage location affect the speed of these services and can I change the location?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am located in Europe and so are all my app's users.
I just noticed that there are different locations available for Storage and Realtime DB.
Right now the location is set to US (I don't believe I was able to choose anything else back when I created the project).

How much does this affect the speed of getting data? In storage I have some audio files and images for instance.

If I would change this how would I go about this? As far as I can read, it is not possible to change this once it is already selected. So would I have to create a new Project to choose new locations for Storage and Realtime DB? How and when would I merge the data? Some users would still be on an older version of the app and thereby use the old DB and store/fetch data so the data across the old project and the new would somehow need to be in sync I suppose?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a new project with both storage and database in Europe, and measuring the performance yourself.

For Storage, you can create a new bucket in your project and create that in any other support location. You can then use that bucket in your project by either [setting it in the configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#add-bucket-url), or by [passing it to the URL storage service when you initialize it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#use_multiple_storage_buckets).

For Realtime Database it is currently not possible to move it to a different region. This may become possible in the future, but I have no timeline or even guarantee on that. If you *must* move the data before that is possible, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.